# The appendChild code is not computing HTML code written inside createTextNode

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to append a separate div with the title "Lucky!" as a child of another div element. I have written the exact code inside the createTextNode event but it is not computing the exact code.

I have tried using different event handlers or writing the JavaScript in different places but nothing will show at all then.

```
function function2() {
    var childtype  = document.createElement("div");
    var childcontent = document.createTextNode("<div title='Lucky!'>See you!</div>");
    childtype.appendChild(childcontent);
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(childtype);
}
function2()
```

It writes `<div title='Lucky!'>See you!</div>` instead of just `See you!` with the properties.

Comment: You can't put a `<div>` in a **text** node. Text nodes are for plain text content, not a subtree of more HTML element nodes.

Comment: Simplest thing to do would be `childtype.innerHTML = "<div ... </div>";`

Comment: @Shilly The name `.createTextNode()` is not chosen arbitrarily - it returns a [`Text` node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). Otherwise `childtype.appendChild(childcontent)` would throw an error.

Comment: @Pointy like this? `var childcontent = childtype.innerHTML = "<div title='Lucky!'>See you!</div>";`

Comment: No, you don't need the `childcontent` variable at all. Just set `.innerHTML` of the parent `<div>` (`childtype`) to that string you've already got.

Comment: `createTextNode` only creates text, it does not parse nodes inside that text. You have to use `createElement()` again for the inner div and add the text to the inner div. Better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create both nodes separately and set the text of the inner node. You can then add the title using `setAttribute()` on the node you created.

```js
function function2() {
    var outer = document.createElement("div");
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    var childcontent = document.createTextNode("See you!");
    inner.appendChild(childcontent);
    inner.setAttribute( 'title', 'Lucky!' );
    outer.appendChild(inner);
    document.body.appendChild(outer); 
}
function2();
```

As mentioned, the alternative is using innerHTML, since that will parse the HTML:

```js
function function2() {
    var childtype = document.createElement("div");
    childtype.innerHTML = "<div title='Lucky!'>See you!</div>";
    document.getElementById("div1").appendChild(childtype);
}
function2();
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```